# Definition of Tate-Shafarevich group , direct product and direct sum

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be a number field and $E/K$ be an elliptic curve.
Let $G_K=Gal(\overline{K}/K)$. Let $M_K$ be a set of all places of $K$.

Tate-Shafarevich group is usually defined as
$$Sha(E/K)\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} Ker(H^1(G_K,E) \to \prod_{v\in M_K} {H^1(G_{K_v},E)})$$

My question is, what  the group

$$Ker(H^1(G_K,E)\to \bigoplus_{v\in M_K} {{H^1}(G_{K_v},E)})$$ looks like.

Is this group worth defining ?

Comment: There is a restriction map $H^1(G_K,E)\to H^1(G_{K_v},E), f\to f\mid_v$ for each $v\in M_K$. We define  the desired map by sending $f$ to $(f\mid_v)$(almost all $f\mid_v$ are zero).

Comment: You're right. In that case, the map $H^1(G_K,E) \to \prod_{v\in M_K} {H^1(G_{K_v},E)}$ has image contained in $\bigoplus_{v\in M_K} {H^1(G_{K_v},E)}$ hence, both maps have the same kernel

Comment: @Lukas Heger. Do you mean that if we send $f$ to $(f\mid_v)$, $(f\mid_v)$ is almost all zero ? This essentially means for fixed $E-$torsor  $C$, $C$ is $K_v$ rational for almost all $v$. Does such a proposition hold ?

Comment: Oh, because good primes of $E/K$, rational points of its reduction lifts by Hensel lemma, for only finitely many $v$, $C$ does not have $K_v$ rational points. I see.